# Uk tax inheritance from overseas parents

Tags: united-kingdom, inheritance

I'm a UK citizen with double nationality from Italy. I live and work in the UK.

I'm receiving some inheritance from my late Father (cash money and shares), who was Italian and resided in Italy.

Are there any taxes to be paid to HMRC for my Italian inheritance if I have this paid to a UK bank account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing to pay to HMRC. UK inheritance tax applies only to UK estates. Assuming that your father did not have any assets that were in the UK at the time of his death, it has no applicability.

Reference: https://www.gov.uk/inheritance-tax/when-someone-living-outside-the-uk-die